# Удобный [или удобные] день и время приёма?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, определения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно писать "удобный" или "удобные" в данном предложении: "Он может согласовать для вас удобный (ые) день и время приёма." И, если нетрудно, уточните, какое правило в русском языке есть по данному вопросу).

Answer (score 1):

Явное предпочтение единственному числу.

http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xliv.html#sect195

§ 195. Определение при существительных – однородных членах

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, здесь нет однозначного ответа. 
Согласно Розенталю:

> Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным – однородным членам, ставится в форме  е д и н с т в е н н о г о  числа, если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например: *российская печать, радио и телевидение*.

Но здесь как раз не всё так очевидно. Фразу **"Он может согласовать для вас удобный (ые) день и время приёма"** можно понять двояко:

- либо он может согласовать и удобный для вас день, и удобное для вас время приема;
- либо он может согласовать удобный для вас день, после чего согласует время приема исходя из его графика на этот день (и не факт, что это время окажется для вас действительно самым удобным).

Поэтому, если имеется в виду первый вариант трактовки, я бы применил множественное число:
**"Он может согласовать для вас удобные день и время приёма"**.
А если подразумевается второй вариант, я бы написал так:
**"Он может согласовать удобный для вас день и назначит вам время приёма"**.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, несмотря на то что глагол в препозиции по отношению к однородным членам, лучше выбрать форму множественного числа, чтобы подчеркнуть, что и день, и время будут удобными.

Сравним:

***Он может согласовать для вас удобные день и время приёма*** (и то и другое будет удобным).

***Он может согласовать для вас удобный день и время приёма*** (понимается двояко, например: день удобный, а время может быть назначено по усмотрению того, кто согласовывает).

**Определение ставится в форме  м н о ж е с т в е н н о г о  числа**, *если по смыслу сочетания при единственном числе было бы неясно, связано ли определение с ближайшим существительным или со всем рядом однородных членов, например: способные ученик и ученица;построить каменные дом и гараж; коричневые шкаф и комод*... [Определение при существительных - однородных членах](http://www.rosental-book.ru/styli_xliv.html)

Answer (score 1):

*Он может согласовать **с вами** удобный  день и время приёма.*

Я думаю, что здесь следует использовать для прилагательного форму  ед.числа м.р. по ближайшему существительному, при этом по смыслу прилагательное будет относиться к обоим существительным.

**При согласовании**  предлагаются свободные **варианты**, из которых посетитель может  выбрать **как удобный день, так и удобное время**.